# Find the value of given expression

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Given:
$$a - \frac1a = b,\qquad b - \frac1b = c, \qquad c - \frac1c = a$$
Find: $\dfrac1{ab} + \dfrac1{bc} + \dfrac1{ac}$
Options: $$a)-3 \qquad b)-1 \qquad c)-6 \qquad d)-9$$

It is based on the image I got from one of my friends. I am getting non-integral value but options are integral.

Comment: would you like to share your working?

Comment: Note that $1/ab$ should be evaluated from left to right giving $b/a$.  I am sure you mean $1/(ab)$.  Stacked fractions are easier to read. What you are looking for is $\frac {a+b+c}{abc}$

Answer (score 2):

Let $X=\frac1{ab}+\frac 1{ac}+\frac1{bc}$.

By adding the three euations, we find that 
$$ \tag1\frac1a+\frac 1b+\frac 1c=0$$
hence
$$\tag2ab+ac+bc=0.$$
Note that from the firat equation  $\frac1{ab}=\frac {a-b}b=\frac ab-1$, and similar for the other equations, so that
$$\tag3X=\frac ab+\frac bc+\frac ca-3.$$
We also have from the first equation that $\frac1{ac}=\frac{a-b}c$, and similar for the other equations,  so that $$\tag4 X=\frac ac-\frac bc+\frac ba-\frac ca+\frac cb-\frac ab$$
Also, using $(2)$,
$$\tag5 0=\left(\frac1{ab}+\frac1{bc}+\frac1{ca}\right)(ab+bc+ac)=3+\frac ac+\frac bc+\frac ab+\frac ba+\frac ca+\frac cb.$$
On the other hand $(4)+2(3)$ says
$$3X= \frac ac+\frac bc+\frac ab+\frac ba+\frac ca+\frac cb-6.$$
Together with $(5)$ this gives us $$X=-3.$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\;a,\;$ set $\;b := a-\frac1a,\; c := b-\frac1b,\; d := c-\frac1c,\; x := a-d.\;$ Factoring expressions gives,
$\;x = \frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c,\quad y := \frac1{ab}+\frac1{bc}+\frac1{ac} = -3 + xa.\;$ Thus, if $\;d=a\;$ then $\;x=0\;$ and $\;y=-3.$

In more detail, 
$$\;a+b+c = \frac{2-6a^2+3a^4}{a^3-a},\quad
ab+ac+bc = abcx = \frac{-1+6a^2-9a^4+3a^6}{a^4-a^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use these equations to get: 
$$\frac{t^4-3t^2+1}{t^3-t}=a$$
where $t=a-\frac{1}{a}$.

Via a graphing calculator, starting with the principal $a\approx0.5077$, we get $b\approx -1.4619$ and $c\approx -0.7779$. Plugging these into the calculator with that accuracy gave me $-3.000021455$. Not exactly rigorous proof but shows the answer you search for is $-3$

My graph: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1unbsdjtks